# How to save a JSON file on the client side and retrieve it later?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Using PHP, I want to create a JSON file with say firstname, lastname.

After I use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode), how can I save it to the client and most importantly, how do I retrieve it and read it?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. You want the client to download this file which was created by php server side script. Right? Are you asking how to save a json fragment to a text file on the server side? What is your `client` - javascript in the browser or something else?

Comment: Yes. I want the client to download the file. Then with javascript, still client side, I will use this information to populate auto-complete and such

Comment: 0 down vote
 

I wish someone had answered this, because I'd like to know too. What I want is to load data on a page, have the user verify that it's OK, and then send it on to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [local storage](http://24ways.org/2010/html5-local-storage)

Or you could simply store the information in a cookie, but that may raise security issues. Plus you'd be sending that data back and forth on each request on your domain (html, css, images, etc.) which can slow down website performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just populate the auto-complete why do you need the file? Implement some RESTful api in the server-side that outputs a json and then consume the json in javascript using:

```
var JSONObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
alert(JSONObject.property1);
```

Here `data` is the json encoded string returned by the server-side.

If you really must save it to file, then I think cookies are the only option you have.

Comment: actually `eval` is not considered safe as it will execute javascript if it's found in `data`. There's a safer way of doing this but I can't remember off the the top of my head.

Comment: I want to avoid pulling from the server so I'm trying to send the information once, make the file expiration very long (like 2 months) because it's slow changing data and let the client get the information locally.

Comment: so you want to download all data on the client side? Doesn't seem right, but if that's what you want, look into `cookies`.